# pass order in passmanager in LLVM

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

What is the order of the passes to be applied to IR if they are added by PassManager? Is it the same order as they were added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. However, if there are some dependent passes they are added as well and then everything (=scheduling of passes) will depend on whether the given pass invalidates the result of some other or note.